# Getting JSON data from URI with PHP without using cURL

Tags: php, json

So, I have a IIS machine with PHP and I need to grab the data from a URI that is returned in JSON format, ie:

http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:GOOG

The trick is, I can't use cURL to do it.  Is there a way to do this so that I have a var that I can then use json_decode() on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:GOOG')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3-PHP-HTTP-client-to-access-Web-site-pages.html

it does what cURL does without using cURL.